# placing javascript into an ebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, winforms

Is it possible to place Javascript into an EBook? Where do I put it?

I tried to put a tally counter into mine then uploaded it and it did not work. Here is the code (it told me to place the top section into the head how can I do this in an ebook?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

new_value = '0';

function increase() { 
    current_value = document.getElementById("counter1").value; 
    new_value = ++current_value; 
    document.getElementById("counter1").value = new_value; 
} 

function reduce() { 
    current_value = document.getElementById("counter1").value; 
    new_value = current_value - 1; 
    document.getElementById("counter1").value = new_value; 
}
</script>

<textarea id="counter1" name="counter1" rows="1" cols="5" class="counter1">0</textarea>
<br> 
<input type="button" value="+" id="add" onclick="increase();" /> 
<input type="button" value="-" id="sub" onclick="reduce();" />
```

The code originally came from Scott Dizzle's tech forum.